# Want to develop mini program with Flutter

Tags: flutter

Can Flutter dev mini-app or not? Like Wechat mini-app. Cos I dont want dev Native app. Spend a lot time. Mini-app is easier to dev.printf("%d\n", 42);

Comment: What is "Mini-app"? Your question doesn't provide much informatino.

Comment: Mini-app is an app that no need install just touch and run on a platform. mini program.

Comment: Any link for more details about Mini-app?

Comment: Perhaps you mean Instant-apps https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16833, https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/

Comment: https://medium.com/goodboxapp/what-is-a-mini-app-3764559ef519

Comment: Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter is a totally different thing from a "mini-app". Flutter is mobile application development SDK for iOS and Android while the latter is just a tool/service (more like wordpress).

Answer (score -3):

Mini-app sounds like a massive privacy invasion. You are asking users to join another application ecosystem to just use your app.

You should list all of your requirements to see whether or not you need it.

Edit:

Developers are working to reduce build sizes for android instant.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16833